# Как запустить команду в Yii2 из его же контроллера

Tags: php, yii2

Через консоль я запуская команду так

```
php yii prepare-file/run 7777.txt
```

она запускается и скрипт обрабатывает переданный через параметр файл 7777.txt.

Но сейчас мне нужно запустить эту команду из экшена контроллера. Что передать в exec();

Пробовал так

```
exec("php yii prepare-file/run " . $file_name . " >/dev/null &");
```

не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать этим способом:

```
# Для начала войдите в нужную дирректорию:
chdir($strPath);// Рут директория

# Теперь запустите nohup, направленную в dev/null, и критически важно со знаком & в конце, чтобы запустилось async:
$output = shell_exec("nohup php yii prepare-file/run " . $file_name . " > /dev/null &");
```

Еще несколько способов с созданием console контроллеров и actions вы можете подсмотреть [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264442/)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте
https://github.com/toriphes/yii2-console-runner

1. Устанавливаем
   `composer require toriphes/yii2-console-runner "*"`
2. Добавляем в конфиг

```
//you config file
'components' => [
    ...
    'consoleRunner' => [
        'class' => 'toriphes\console\Runner'
    ]
    ...
]
```

3. Запускаем свои команды так:

```
//some application file
$output = '';
Yii::$app->consoleRunner->run('controller/action param1 param2 ...', $output);
echo $output; //prints the command output
```